# Embed Javascript code to registered users only

Tags: plugins, php, javascript

I am having a javascript code which i embed to the footer.php of my wordpress site to be shown on all the pages.

The javascript code is for a livechat support program.

My question is how do I make this livechat window available only to registered users or members?

PN: I am also using a third party plugin as a membership plugin.

Thanks,

Comment: What role/capability determines registered users or members?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress provides the [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). I think [is_user_logged_in()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Is_User_Logged_in) tag will work for you. List of conditional tags available.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in()  ) 
{
  // include the JavaScript File
}
```

**UPDATE:** Also if you want to check the user roles etc.. you can use the [current_user_can()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) you can check both the both roles and capabilities.
Better to use the wp_get_current_user(); function like :

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$roles = array('editor', 'author');

if( array_intersect($roles, $current_user->roles ) && is_user_logged_in() ) {

   // include javascript file here etc...

}
```